# Images and text in a JFace SWT TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, cells, tableviewer

I'm currently trying to implement a dynamic Dialog containing an SWT Table with a JFace TableViewer on top of it. When the Dialog is instantiated it gets passed an Array for the column headlines which are then created dynamically (this works already), it also gets passed a java.util.HashMap containing value pairs. Each pair is supposed to represents one row, like ("1", Set of data for the row as in data for every cell of the row). Now as far as I have gathered from several tutorials, table input seems to be controlled over the getElements() method of the content provider, which grabs its parameter, the input element when setInput() is called. If I am right so far, how would I go about filling the cells of the row when different pieces of cell data are of different types, i.e. Text | Image | Image | Text | Text |. I'm thinking either I haven't understood the content provider or this isn't as simple as I thought before I started doing it, since I have no idea how I am gonna return an Object[] in getElements() representing the cell structure described above. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1):

I think content provider does not really care about different types in table cells. Label provider however does care. Label provider is for representing some user readable "information" about the underlying input. `ITableLabelProvider` has `public Image getColumnImage(final Object element, final int columnIndex)` and `public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex);`. As you can see implementing these methods you will have the column number and the actual object in the specific cell. With some 'instanceof's you can show text/images... depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how I am gonna return an Object[] in getElements() representing the cell structure described above

`Object[]` is also an `Object`, and `Object[][]` (or `List<Object>[]`) is `Object[]`.